# Strange behavior using tempfile.mkdtemp() in virtualenvs when launched in Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, virtualenv

I am seeing inconsistent behavior when creating temporary directories in Python:

```
# System Python, Windows Console

C:\Python33>python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile.mkdtemp()
'c:\\windows\\temp\\tmpte7fcc'


# Virtualenv Python, Windows Console

Scripts>python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile.mkdtemp()
'c:\\windows\\temp\\tmprziefb'

# System Python, Cygwin Console

$ /cygdrive/c/Python33/python.exe
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile.mkdtemp()
'c:\\windows\\temp\\tmprk4fcu'

# Virtualenv Python, Cygwin Console

$ Scripts/python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile.mkdtemp()
'c:\\cygwin\\tmp\\tmppeozcl
```

The first three cases create temporary directories in `C:\Windows\Temp` (as expected). Why does the fourth case create temporary directories somewhere else?

---

**EDIT:** Additional data requested in the comments:

```
# System Python, Windows Console

C:\Python33>python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile._candidate_tempdir_list()
['C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP', 'c:\\temp', 'c:\\tmp', '\\temp', '\\tmp', 'C:\\Python33']
>>> [os.environ.get(envname) for envname in ('TMPDIR', 'TEMP', 'TMP')]
[None, 'C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP']


# Virtualenv Python, Windows Console

Scripts>python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile._candidate_tempdir_list()
['C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP', 'c:\\temp', 'c:\\tmp', '\\temp', '\\tmp', 'C:\\_PROJECTS\\python-veracity']
>>> [os.environ.get(envname) for envname in ('TMPDIR', 'TEMP', 'TMP')]
[None, 'C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP']

# System Python, Cygwin Console

$ /cygdrive/c/Python33/python.exe
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile._candidate_tempdir_list()
['C:\\Cygwin\\tmp', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP', 'c:\\temp', 'c:\\tmp', '\\temp', '\\tmp', 'C:\\_PROJECTS\\python-veracity']
>>> [os.environ.get(envname) for envname in ('TMPDIR', 'TEMP', 'TMP')]
[None, 'C:\\Cygwin\\tmp', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP']

# Virtualenv Python, Cygwin Console

$ Scripts/python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile._candidate_tempdir_list()
['C:\\Cygwin\\tmp', 'C:\\Cygwin\\tmp', 'c:\\temp', 'c:\\tmp', '\\temp', '\\tmp', 'C:\\_PROJECTS\\python-veracity']
>>> [os.environ.get(envname) for envname in ('TMPDIR', 'TEMP', 'TMP')]
[None, 'C:\\Cygwin\\tmp', 'C:\\Cygwin\\tmp']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tempfile module looks for the environment variables TMPDIR, TEMP and TMP. If one of these variables is set then its value is used as base directory for temporary files and directories. I guess Cygwin sets one of these to C:\cygwin\tmp.

Comment: any idea why this only happens in the virtualenv?

Comment: What's the output of `tempfile._candidate_tempdir_list()` and `[os.environ.get(envname) for envname in ('TMPDIR', 'TEMP', 'TMP')]` for each variant?

Comment: I have updated the question with the data you requested. Apparently the `virtualenv` environment also sets `TMP` and that's what `mkdtemp()` uses?